# OpenGL : how to get the matrix that mirror the Scene?

Tags: c++, opengl, linear-algebra, transformation, glm-math

**Context:**

I try to make a mirror in OpenGL.
So what I need to define a mirror is a plane, defined by a point `p` and two normal vectors `n1` and `n2`. `n3=n1^n2` defines a vector oriented to the viewer of the mirror (the sign is important to `discard` fragments that are behind the mirror and also would be reflected in front of the mirror). `n1`, `n2` and `n3` define a basis in the coordinates of the mirror (with origin `p` an arbitrary point located on the mirror plane).

Now, to draw the reflection of the scene I need the matrix `reflectionMatrix` that transform any point into its mirrored. I don't even know if it's possible, but what I tried looks ok but there is problems when the mirror is very close to the point.

I tried to use transition matrix used in linear algebra, but I don't even know if I can use them with transformation matrix. I am also a bit confused about the transformation order.

The code is that :

```cpp
/// @brief Compute change-of-basis matrix.
/// From basis {e1, e2, e3} to canonical basis of R^3.
mat4 transition(const glm::vec3& e1, const glm::vec3& e2, const glm::vec3& e3)
{
    // GLM is column major: mat4(col1, col2, col3, col4)
    return {
       vec4(e1, 0),
       vec4(e2, 0),
       vec4(e3, 0),
       vec4(vec3(0), 1)
   };
}

glm::mat4 getReflectionMatrix() {
            const glm::vec3 mirrorPos{scene.mirrorPos};
            const glm::vec3 n1{1, 0, 0};
            const glm::vec3 n2{0, 1, 0};
            const glm::vec3 n3{glm::cross(n1, n2)};
            
            // n1, n2 are orthogonal vectors of the mirror
            // n3 is to complete the basis
            // the vertices should be in trigonometric order to work
            glm::mat4 reflectionMatrix{1};
            // Let p be the point we mirror
            // Compute p1 = p relative to the mirror [Translation in global coordinate system ~= premultiply]
            reflectionMatrix = glm::translate(reflectionMatrix, -mirrorPos);
            // Compute p2 = same as p1 but in coordinate system {n1, n2, n3}
            reflectionMatrix *= glm::inverse(transition(n1, n2, n3));
            // Compute p3 = (p2.x, p2.y, -p2.z) to go into the mirror (z is orthogonal distance from mirror)
            reflectionMatrix = glm::scale(reflectionMatrix, {1, 1, -1});
                      
            // Compute p4 = same as p3 but in canonical coordinate system (again relative to the mirror)
            reflectionMatrix *= transition(n1, n2, n3);
            // Compute p5 = p4 from relative to the mirror to global space [Translation in global coordinate system]
            reflectionMatrix = glm::translate(reflectionMatrix, mirrorPos);
            return reflectionMatrix;
}
```

**What is wrong with the reflection matrix?**  <sub><sup>Or is there a simpler way</sup></sub>

Comment: [tag:glm] (generalized linear models) != [tag:glm-math] (GLM - OpenGL Mathematics)

Comment: From what I see in your example, transition shouldn't matter at all since it should (due to the choice of n1 and n2) contain an identity matrix, but in general, the way how you build your matrix should work out.

Comment: What's unclear to me is why you set the uniform in the middle of the method. And your matrix order is for translations is wrong. first translate needs mirrorPos, second one -mirrorPos

Comment: @BDL I remember it's exactly what happened. If i switch the sign it works, but isn't it illogical ? To get the position of `p` relative to the mirror should'nt we do `p-m` ?

Comment: @BDL Also the uniform is a copy-paste, it's because I need the matrix to get the depth in the mirror to discard fragment from the other side. Yes I was unsure of the pre/post multiply translation order, I tried with both but it appears to not matter. But will it work for any `n1`, `n2` ?

Comment: As long as they are normalized and form a orthogonal space, it should work, but I haven't tested it. About order: You need to translate by -pos first to get pos to the origin. Since we are M * v as multiplication order, the last operation you write down is the first one executed.

Comment: Ok I have found my problem : I get n1 and n2 on world coords by doing M * (x,y,z,1) which is wrong instead of M * (x,y,z,0)